# Distribution of money to satisfy a condition

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say that I have $n$ people. I have $m$ dollars, and I want to create bills of any number of dollars, such that the total value of the bills sum to $m$. I want to ensure that this set of bills is sufficient so that all distributions of money among the $n$ people can be satisfied by the set. What is the minimum number of bills that must be printed?

For example, if I have 5 people and 8 dollars, I can have the following distribution: 4 \$1 bills and 2 \$2 bills, which would amount to an answer of 6. This would be able to satisfy all distributions of coins, i.e. (1,1,1,1,4), (1,1,1,2,3), (1,1,2,2,2), (0,1,1,1,5), etc.

By satisfy I mean that the bills can be given to the people with each person having the right amount of money. Of course, you can't split bills.

If $m\leq n$, then I think the answer would just be $m$. Otherwise, I'm not so sure.

Comment: This question is from an ongoing summer camp application [SPARC 2017](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfdyy88b3SKls9r6abmn95_lNxUa41KyqFLsDyuFZoRP-7xJg/viewform?c=0&w=1) and should be put on hold until the deadline has passed.

Comment: Question is from the [SPARC 2017 1st Round Application](https://goo.gl/forms/iKoCXB7MdyM5Xu4x1) (Minting coins). The application deadline is 8 March 2017, and this question will remain locked as per our [Contest Question policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16774) until after this date.